# eclipse cdt value not shown correctly during debug, always 0

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I am trying eclipse CDT out. But the eclipse is not showing the value of variables correctly. Both in the "Variables" window and "Expressions" window.

[image]
But in the "Variables" window, value of `x` and `y` are both shown as 0. Where, the correct value should be 1 and 2.

[image]

Per the request from comment, here is the environment I run into the problem.

- MacOS Sierra (10.12.3)
- gdb 7.12.1 installed from brew
- Neon.1a Release (4.6.1)

Answer (score 0):

Click the inverted triangle and select "String" as the number format as following.
[image]

Comment: Hi @PengZhang I am please you found a solution, but this should not be the solution as you may have exposed a bug in Eclipse or GDB. Can you expand on the environment you were using as I can't reproduce on Ubuntu with GDB 7.12 and Eclipse Neon. Thanks!

Comment: @JonahGraham I have just added description of the environment. Please let me know if you need more input. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, I don't have access to a Mac, I will see if I can get someone else to reproduce.

Comment: Hi @PengZhang, Can you provide the MI traces of the failing case. 1) Preferences -> C/C++ -> Debug -> GDB and check "Show the GDB traces consoles ..." 2) In the Console View, change to "... gdb traces" and include that output for a case where the UI is displaying the wrong thing. Thanks!